# Intel TBB, parallel_pipeline, error when I pass const char* between stages

Tags: c++, string, char, ifstream, tbb

I have the following pipeline:

```
parallel_pipeline(20,
       make_filter<void,const char*>(
          filter::serial,
          [&](flow_control& fc)->const char*
          {
            getline(fe,orden_fichero);
            if(fe.eof())
            {
              fc.stop(); // stop processing
              return nullptr;
            }
            else
            {
              return orden_fichero.c_str();
            }
          }
        ) &
      make_filter<const char*,void>(
          filter::parallel,
          [&](const char* p){

              string orden(p);
          }
        )
      );
```

Before, when I use string instead of `const char*`, and the first return was `orden_fichero` without the conversion to `const char*`, the program worked well, but very slow. I have seen that working with `const char*` could improve the performance of the program, but in this way, some of the lines are not received correctly in the second stage of the pipeline (Some of the lines lack characters) For example in a 10M lines file, 26 lines corresponding to orden string, have size 0, 9 have size between 2 and 35 and all the rest are recived correctly (the order variable have 36 characters or more)

- How I could recive correctly a const char* from the firts pipeline intro the second one?.
- There is some way to read a file in Intel TBB in order to do operations on each line in parallel and save the result in a vector in a better way that the one that I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you first were returning a copy of `orden_fichero` (which I guess is a std::string). With your current code you are returning a pointer to the internal data of `orden_fichero`, so when thread 1 (first pipeline stage) reads a line from the file and stores it in `orden_fichero` the data is corrupted, when it is read from thread 2 (second pipeline stage).

Some ways of how to correctly return a c string are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24013775/7699037) (especially I would recommend version 2). But again this will allocate a lot of memory and is most probably almost as inefficient as returning a std::string.

You could try to create a new string outside of the `parallel_pipeline`, copy the `c_str` of orden_fichero into that string and then return the pointer to that. But I'm not sure this will work correctly...

```
std::string another_string;
parallel_pipeline(20,
       make_filter<void,const char*>(
          filter::serial,
          [&](flow_control& fc)->const char*
          {
            getline(fe,orden_fichero);
            if(fe.eof())
            {
              fc.stop(); // stop processing
              return nullptr;
            }
            else
            {
              another_string = orden_fichero;
              return another_string.c_str();
            }
          }
        ) &
      make_filter<const char*,void>(
          filter::parallel,
          [&](const char* p){

              string orden(p);
          }
        )
      );
```

So, while data is read into `orden_fichero` through `getline`, `another_string` can safely be used. But as I said, I'm not sure this is going to work correctly, because the thread of the second pipeline stage might get preempted before `const char* p` get's copied into `orden` and the thread of the first stage might then overwrite `another_string` and invalidate `p`. You could try to protect `another_string` with a mutex, but I guess this would slow down things again.